# Vue various product search

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a bit of code that searches for:

- name
- category
- tag
- area

It's okay but I have an issue with searching for a favourite.

Name, category, tag and area are search this function:

```
 return this.meals.filter(meal => {
    return meal.strMeal.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
     && (category === "All" || meal.strCategory === category)
     && (area === "All" || meal.strArea === area)
     && (tag === "All" || String(meal.strTags).includes(tag))
  })
```

This is how I render my loop:

```
 <li v-for="meal of filteredList">
```

I have 2 modals, but this modal has to work on click. For example, I click on a product, search only on this product. How can I connect this to `filteredList`?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is **IN** not of.

`<li v-for="meal in filteredList">`

Think of it like this, it's a for loop. It loops through all of the items in the array. So, for each item **IN** the array.

You could look at it like this:

`<li v-for="item in array">`

If you need to access the index of these items you can also do this:

`<li v-for="(item, index) in array" :key="index">`